# У QDialogButtonBox изменяется размер при установке в Stylesheet border и border-radius. Как это исправить?

Tags: python, pyqt, qss, qpushbutton, qdialogbuttonbox

При установке в StyleSheet: `border` и  `border-radius` размер кнопок становится минимальным и его не получается увеличить с помощью 
`setMinimumSize()`, `setFixedSize()`, s`etBaseSize()`.

Выравнивать размеры кнопок с помощью `padding` не вариант, так как это только пример, а в программе для которой данное диалоговое окно применяется, StyleSheet для этих кнопок глобально устанавливается через `QPushButton`, и Stylesheet отдельно (как в примере ниже) для кнопок не устанавливается.

Диалоговое окно созданное в QtCreator:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(413, 83)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.formLayout.setRowWrapPolicy(QtWidgets.QFormLayout.WrapLongRows)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.buttonBox.setFont(font)
        self.buttonBox.setStyleSheet("    color: #27c727;\n"
"    border: 2px solid #555555;\n"
"    border-radius: 5px;\n"
"    background-color:\n"
"    QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,\n"
"    stop: 0 #888,\n"
"    stop:0.1 #666,\n"
"    stop:0.5 #454545,\n"
"    stop:1 #353535);")
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setCenterButtons(True)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) # type: ignore
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject) # type: ignore
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "asdfasfasfaf"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем уверен, что правильно понимаю, то что вы хотите сделать, но попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(413, 83)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.formLayout.setRowWrapPolicy(QtWidgets.QFormLayout.WrapLongRows)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout)
        
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.buttonBox.setFont(font)
        self.buttonBox.setStyleSheet("    color: #27c727;\n"
"    border: 2px solid #555555;\n"
"    border-radius: 5px;\n"
"    background-color:\n"
"    QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,\n"
"    stop: 0 #888,\n"
"    stop:0.1 #666,\n"
"    stop:0.5 #454545,\n"
"    stop:1 #353535);")
        
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setCenterButtons(True)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) # type: ignore
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject) # type: ignore
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "asdfasfasfaf"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # кнопка не в QDialogButtonBox, добавил для теста
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        
        # тут ваша логика
        
        
#vvvvvvvvv <---------------------------------------------------------------
Stylesheet = '''
QDialogButtonBox QPushButton {
    font-size: 24px;
    min-width:  96px;                                           /* <---- */
    min-height: 96px;                                           /* <---- */
}
'''        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)                                # +++
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как раз то что нужно! Спасибо за помощь. А почему размеры изменяются и не устанавливаются через стандартные методы, не знаете? С обычными кнопками такого нет.

Comment: @Alex пожалуйста.